# Cómo puedo mostrar todos los datos de una tabla "X" de un campo "Y" dentro de un select option

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

estoy teniendo problemas con querer mostrar todos los datos de un campo de una tabla de mi base de datos, lo que quiero hacer es que al usar un select option, se pueda mostrar todos los datos de un campo en concreto dejo una imagen de la base de datos lo que está encerrado en un cuadrado es lo que quiero mostrar en mi select que pida esos 3 datos de **vNomBancotab** ya que solo me muestra 1, de antemano agradezco la ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que hice es así:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <?php
session_start();
    require("connect_db.php");

    $sql=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM tabbancos");
    if($f=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){

            $row['vNomBancotab']=$f['vNomBancotab'];

    }

    echo $row['vNomBancotab']; /*esto solo lo puse para comprobar que si jala el dato del campo de la tabla*/



?>
</head>
<body>

<select class="custom-select" name="SelectBanco" id="SelectBanco" required="">
<option disabled="disabled" value="" selected>Elegir...</option>
<option value="<?php echo $row['vNomBancotab'];?>"></option>  <!--Aqui es donde no me muestra nada o solo me llega a mostrar un solo dato-->
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que iterar sobre los resultados de tu query con un bucle.  De lo contrario, de la manera que lo estas haciendo, solo estas tomando uno de los registros.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <?php
    session_start();
    require("connect_db.php");
    $row = '';
    $sql=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM tabbancos");
    while($f=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){    
            $row .= "<option value='" . $f['vNomBancotab'] . "'>" . 
                         $f['vNomBancotab'] . "</option>";    
    }        

?>
</head>
<body>

<select class="custom-select" name="SelectBanco" id="SelectBanco" required="">
<option disabled="disabled" value="" selected>Elegir...</option>
<?php echo $row;?>">
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <?php
      session_start();
      require("connect_db.php");

    ?>
</head>
<body>

<select class="custom-select" name="SelectBanco" id="SelectBanco" required="">
<option disabled="disabled" value="" selected>Elegir...</option>
  <?php 

   $sql=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM tabbancos");
        while($f=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){    

            echo '<option value="'.$f['vNomBancotab'].'">'.$f['vNomBancotab'].'</option>';

   }

  ?>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

otra forma de hacerlo en algunas lineas menos y con menos variables. :)
SI te se sirve marcala como buena By: srJJ